# How to set different UITableViewCellStyle for different sets of cells in the same table?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Hi I am implementing a UITableView. I intend to use a different UITableViewCellStyle for different sets of cells depending on a certain criteria (see code snippet below)

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier]autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
}

if ([genericObj.type isEqualToString:@"question"]) 
{
    //I want to user UITableViewCellStyleValue1
}
else if([genericObj.type isEqualToString:@"topic"])
{
    //I want to user UITableViewCellStyleValue2
}
else //user
{
    //I want to user UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
}
```

Can anyone advise me how I can change the uitableviewcellstyle accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the Style of a UITableViewCell after it has been initialized.

Instead use a different reuse identifier.

Place the if then else above the if (cell == nil) line. From those dequeue the different types of cells you need.

And if the cell is nil, then init the cell you need within another if then else block.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended you to take a look at this useful cell creation pattern: http://www.digitalhobbit.com/2009/12/19/a-useful-uitableview-cell-creation-pattern/

It's really helpful and will do exactly what you ask.